# How to compare two list records in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a custom button in detail page.

When i click the button it redirects to the VF page.In the Vf page I want to display the list of carset records except the deatil page record.And i want to get the value of selected checkbox.Based on the checkbox value i will get the List for the selected picklist.From the detailPage record id i will get some Lis.In bothe list I want to compare the field called `Displayed_Code_Label__c`

**Apex:**

```
public class Sample_AdditionalServices_CLS {
public String strCurrentRecId{get;set;}
public String strOrderId{get;set;}
public String strOptionVal {get;set;}
public String strCarsetOption{get;set;}
public string strNWservice{get;set;}
public string strCBservice{get;set;}
public string strOtherservice{get;set;}
public string strContreOption{get;set;}

public List<Sample_Car_Set__c> lstCarset=new List<Sample_Car_Set__c>();
public List<SelectOption> lstOptions  = new List<SelectOption>();

    public Sample_AdditionalServices_CLS(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        strCurrentRecId= apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('carSetID');

        strOrderId=apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('orderID');

        system.debug('strCurrentRecId>>>>'+strCurrentRecId);
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOptions(){


        lstCarset=[select name from Sample_Car_Set__c where Order__c=:strOrderId];
        lstOptions .add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        for(Sample_Car_Set__c strC2Goptions:lstCarset) {

            if(strC2Goptions.id!=strCurrentRecId)
            lstOptions .add(new SelectOption(strC2Goptions.id,strC2Goptions.name));

        }

        system.debug('lstOptions >>>>'+lstOptions );
        return lstOptions ;
    }


    public void retrieveService() {
    system.debug('Selected Values >>>>'+strCarsetOption+strNWservice+strCBservice+strOtherservice+strContreOption);

    if(strNWservice=='true') {

     List<Service__c> lstNWService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Network' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
      List<Service__c> lstCurNWService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Network' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
     system.debug('lstNWService >>>>'+lstNWService);

     } 
     if(strCBservice=='true') {

        List<Service__c> lstCBService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Coach-Builder' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
        List<Service__c> lstCurCBService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Coach-Builder' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
        system.debug('lstCBService >>>>'+lstCBService);
    }
     if(strOtherservice=='true') {

         List<Service__c> lstOtherService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Other' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];

         List<Service__c> lstCurOtherService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Other' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
         system.debug('lstOtherService >>>>'+lstOtherService);
    }
     if(strContreOption=='true') {


    List<Service__c> lstContreOption=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Contremarque Option' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];

    List<Service__c> lstCurContreOption=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Contremarque Option' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
    system.debug('lstContreOption>>>>'+lstContreOption);
    }



        }

    public Pagereference customSave() {
    system.debug('Selected Values >>>>'+strCarsetOption+strNWservice+strCBservice+strOtherservice+strContreOption);

    return null;
    }

}
```

**VF:**

```
 <apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!customSave}" /> 
    <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" />
</apex:pageblockbuttons>


<apex:pageblocksection columns="1" >

    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Carset</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList size="1"  value="{!strCarsetOption}" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options }" > </apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="a"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
     <apex:outputLabel > Network services</apex:outputLabel>
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strNWservice}"> <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch1"/>
     </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Coach-Builder services</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strCBservice}">  <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch2"/>              
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Other services</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strOtherservice}">   <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch3"/>          
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Contremarque options</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strContreOption}"> <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch4"/>            
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>



    </apex:pageblocksection>
```

For eg:If i have in the `List<Service__c> lstContreOption` 2 values where `Displayed_Code_Label__c` have `TWIZY` and `CAROO` ,
`List<Service__c> lstCurContreOption` 2 values where `Displayed_Code_Label__c` have `TWIZY` and `CAROO95`
I want `List<service__c>` with `CAROO,TWIZY,CAROO95` records.How to obtain this ?

Comment: try to initialize `lstOptions ` inside  `getOptions` function when you click on save `getOptions` function will call because it is get Method and it will reinitialize and get the picklist values again

Comment: thank you:) I want to get the selected checkbox value.Based on the selection i want to get the query value .@Ratan

Comment: you are already assigning value to `strCarsetOption` this variable, are you getting the value in this variable or not ?

Comment: yeah am getting